# Missing dependencies for reactive Jersey HTTP client

Tags: java, jersey-client

I have the following dependencies copied below in my pom.xml file.  However, I do not appear to have all the required dependencies to use the RX Jersry client because when I make the following call, I get a runtime exception complaining about no class def found.

```
 final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

**exception**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-rxjava2</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-java8</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: "I get a runtime exception complaining about no class def found." Please post a Stack Trace and maybe the import statements.

Comment: @Clijsters added

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a StackTrace. The full StackTrace could show us _which_ class is missing.

Comment: Don't mix your Jersey versions and remove the hk2-api (it is already pulled in by Jersey)